# MorphaStemmer Lemminizer Issue

Tags: java, lemmatization

I am using MorphaStemmer 1.5 to get the singular form of words.
But here its giving stem base for every words.
Example if search for bowling, it gives bowl.
If i use led its giving lead.I have tried with lot of words
its works fine,It is found that what ever word we gave , it is converting it to its base. I need to restrict this and only convert if it has singular otherwise return the same?
I just need to convert to its base form if it is plural only.

```
  MorphaStemmer o=new MorphaStemmer();
    System.out.println(o.stem("bowling"));
```

Any Help?